# Sub query retrieving all record counts

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am attempting to do something which may be impossible.

However I want to write a subquery that retrieves the number of opens and the number of clicks I have recorded in one table.

I am getting an issue where the inner query (the sub query) is retrieving the count of all the of the clicks. The outer query is fine (it's doing what it's supposed to do)..but the inner query seems like it's giving an aggregated count (i.e everything in the list).

When I put `WHERE` clauses in both of the queries (outer & inner) I get the desired results.

Can I achieve what I want to do or will I need to have another solution?

This is the query:

```
SELECT        
      tbl1SentEmails.lngMergeID
      , COUNT(DISTINCT tbl1EmailEvents.strEmailSendID) AS lngOpens
      , (SELECT        
              COUNT(DISTINCT tbl1EmailEvents.strEmailSendID) AS lngClicks
         FROM tbl1EmailEvents 
         INNER JOIN tbl1SentEmails 
         ON tbl1EmailEvents.strEmailSendID = tbl1SentEmails.strEmailSendID
        WHERE  (tbl1EmailEvents.strType = N'C')
        ) AS lngClicks
FROM  tbl1EmailEvents 
INNER JOIN tbl1SentEmails  
    ON tbl1EmailEvents.strEmailSendID = tbl1SentEmails.strEmailSendID
GROUP BY tbl1SentEmails.lngMergeID, tbl1EmailEvents.strType
HAVING        (tbl1EmailEvents.strType = N'O')
```

This is some sample data with input/output:

This is what I'm currently getting with the query above:

[image]

And this is what I am expecting to get:

[image]

Comment: Could your query not be simplified by using `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tbl1EmailEvents.strType = N'O' THEN tbl1EmailEvents.strEmailSendID END), COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tbl1EmailEvents.strType = N'C' THEN  tbl1EmailEvents.strEmailSendID END)` without the `HAVING` clause and removing the `GROUP BY` on strType?

Comment: can you provide some example data?  ie, input and expected output?

Comment: @DForck42 just added 2 screen shots

Comment: FYI, the reason lngClicks is doing that is because your subquery isn't joining to anything in the outer query. You could change the subquery to link to the outer query with something like this: `(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tbl1EmailEvents.strEmailSendID) FROM tbl1EmailEvents EE INNER JOIN tbl1SentEmails SE ON EE.strEmailSendID = SE.strEmailSendID WHERE EE.strType = N'C' AND EE.lnkMergeID = tbl1EmailEvents.lnkMergeID) AS lngClicks`. But again, I think your query could be simplified as in my other comment.

Comment: @ZLK, I just tried your query it works as expected. I'll turn this into a view and see the performance of it. Thnx. I'll get back to you soon.